# magento2 created custom product attribute but missing in mass update

Tags: php, magento2, entity-attribute-value

I've created an attribute programmatically like this

```
                $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                Product::ENTITY,
                self::mpn,
                [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'mpn',
                    'input' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => '',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => '',
                ]
            );
```

However when I try to select multiple products and mass update this attribute, it doesn't show up.

When I recreated it from the backend it shows up.

Could anyone let me know what option I'm missing so that it appears correctly to perform mass updates on it?

This happens in Magento 2.2.6, 2.2.7 and 2.3 when I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your problem because you are missing input type.

Please change this:

```
'input' => ''
```

to any specific type. Example:

```
'input' => 'text'
```

Regards

Comment: Nice, I've been busting my head as to why it wouldn't show up :) thank you